# read_csv does not open the csv

Tags: csv, pandas

I tried to open the csv file (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/) with the pandas module, but the read_csv command did not open the file properly.

```
import pandas
bankfull = pandas.read_csv('bank-full.csv')
print bankfull.head()
```

and the result looks like

```
age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y
0  58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143...
```

1  44;"technician";"single";"secondary";"no";29;"...

how can I fix the code so the csv file import as proper pandas Dataframe?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the separator arg `sep=';'`, the default is comma `,` you can check the docs for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', sep=';')
Out[27]:
       age            job   marital  education default  balance housing loan  \
0       58     management   married   tertiary      no     2143     yes   no   
1       44     technician    single  secondary      no       29     yes   no   
2       33   entrepreneur   married  secondary      no        2     yes  yes   
3       47    blue-collar   married    unknown      no     1506     yes   no   
4       33        unknown    single    unknown      no        1      no   no   
5       35     management   married   tertiary      no      231     yes   no   
6       28     management    single   tertiary      no      447     yes  yes   
7       42   entrepreneur  divorced   tertiary     yes        2     yes   no   
8       58        retired   married    primary      no      121     yes   no   
9       43     technician    single  secondary      no      593     yes   no   
10      41         admin.  divorced  secondary      no      270     yes   no   
11      29         admin.    single  secondary      no      390     yes   no
```